# What SRID is this projection?

Tags: coordinate-system, srid

Anyone know what the SRID is for the following projected coordinate reference system:

```
{
   PROJCS   [
      "Florida 0901, Eastern Zone [1983, US Survey feet]",
      GEOGCS      [
         "NAD 83 [Continental US]",
         DATUM         [
            "NAD 83 [Continental US]",
            SPHEROID            [
               "GRS 80",
               6378137.0,
               298.257222101
            ]
         ],
         PRIMEM         [
            "Greenwich",
            0.0
         ],
         UNIT         [
            "Decimal Degree",
            0.0174532925199433
         ]
      ],
      PROJECTION      [
         "Transverse_Mercator"
      ],
      PARAMETER      [
         "False_Easting",
         656166.666667
      ],
      PARAMETER      [
         "Central_Meridian",
         -81.0
      ],
      PARAMETER      [
         "Scale_Factor",
         0.9999411764705882
      ],
      PARAMETER      [
         "Latitude_Of_Origin",
         24.33333333333333
      ],
      UNIT      [
         "U.S. Foot",
         0.304800609601219
      ]
   ]
}
```

My guess is: [102658](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102658/). I'm assuming I can just make sure all the different values are the same and I'm good.

Comment: yep that is good

Comment: The above definition technically doesn't match Esri:102658 because of the projCRS, geogCRS and datum names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EPSG:2236 would do as well: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2236/html/

Your SRID is by ESRI, and might not be understood by other software.

Comment: You can use http://epsg.io/2236 to see other export formats.